# ¿Se pueden usar las comillas para resaltar?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Viniendo para el trabajo en coche he visto una furgoneta de una empresa que anunciaba lo siguiente:

> Detección de fugas de agua "sin obras".

Esto sigue el patrón de resaltado que he visto algunas veces, como un cartel que vi en una finca que ponía:

> "Prohibido" aparcar.

El texto en la furgoneta imagino que quería recalcar el hecho de que no hacen obras, aunque a mí la sensación que me produce es que el texto en realidad quiere decir:

> Detección de fugas de agua sin obras, o casi.

Y el texto de la finca me parece que dice:

> No te podemos legalmente prohibir que aparques, pero por favor no lo hagas.

Esto se basa en el [artículo del DPD sobre las comillas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=comillas), que recoge su uso para delimitar textos de estilo irónico, palabras impropias o dobles sentidos.

Suponiendo que la empresa realmente garantiza que no hacen obras, y que lo que querían era resaltar el texto, ¿recomiendan la RAE, Fundéu o similares este uso de las comillas en algún caso? Si no, ¿cuál es la alternativa?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que sí es el uso (a veces dicho prescriptivamente [incorrecto](https://comohacerunensayobien.com/uso-de-las-comillas/)) de [comillas irónicas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)<sup>[1](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=682713)</sup> para enfatizar una palabra:

> **2) Para enfatizar una palabra.** La utilización en textos de palabras entrecomilladas como las vistas en los ejemplos de carteles es cada vez más habitual. El escritor quiere remarcar una palabra y **en lugar de utilizar negrita o un subrayado** usa las comillas de un modo incorrecto.
>
> Ejemplo:
>
> > La nueva Miss Mundo es realmente “guapa” sobre todo si la comparamos con las candidatas de otros países.

Y que las opciones "kosher" serían negritas, cursiva, subrayas, o mayúsculas.

No obstante, Fundéu dice esto:

> #### Funciones básicas de la cursiva
>
> ...
>
> **Las principales funciones de la cursiva son de énfasis** y para señalarle al lector que un sintagma o una palabra común puede resultarle ajena por ser un
>   neologismo, formar parte de una jerga o argot, adoptar una forma incorrecta
>   o funcionar como metalenguaje, es decir, no formar parte del discurso con el
>   sentido propio de las palabras.

> #### Comillas como alternativa
>
> **Cuando aplicar la cursiva no es técnicamente factible, pueden usarse comillas.**
>   En textos manuscritos es costumbre aplicar un subrayado, y en internet
>   no es raro delimitar el texto con _ o con /.
>
> - https://www.fundeu.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/CursivasGuiaFundeu.pdf

Comment: ***NEGRITAS, SUBRAYADO Y MAYÚSCULAS*** para que parezca que lo estamos gritando

Comment: Las cursivas siempre me han parecido siempre como notas de *interes*, casi una referencia de énfasis menor a las negritas o al subrayado. incluso como referencias